# pandas dataframe groupby like mysql, yet into new column

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[11,11,22,22],'mask':[0,0,0,1],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})
df

    A   mask    values
0    11  0   10
1    11  0   15
2    22  0   20
3    22  1   25
```

Now how can I group by A, and keep the column names in tact, and yet put a custom function into Z:

```
def calculate_df_stats(dfs):

    mask_ = list(dfs['B'])
    mean = np.ma.array(list(dfs['values']), mask=mask_).mean()
    return mean

df['Z'] = df.groupby('A').agg(calculate_df_stats) # does not work
```

and generate:

```
     A   mask   values   Z
0    11  0        10    12.5
1    22  0        20    25
```

Whatever I do it only replaces values column with the masked mean.

and can your solution be applied for a function on two columns and return in a new column?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
To clarify more: let's say I have such a table in Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `Reader_datapoint` WHERE `wavelength` = '560' 
LIMIT 200;
```

which gives me such result:
http://pastebin.com/qXiaWcJq

If I run now this:

```
SELECT *, avg(action_value) FROM `Reader_datapoint` WHERE `wavelength` = '560' 
group by `reader_plate_ID`;
```

I get:

```
datapoint_ID    plate_ID    coordinate_x    coordinate_y    res_value   wavelength  ignore  avg(action_value)
193 1   0   0   2.1783  560 NULL    2.090027083333334
481 2   0   0   1.7544  560 NULL    1.4695583333333333
769 3   0   0   2.0161  560 NULL    1.6637885416666673
```

How can I replicate this behaviour in Pandas? note that all the column names stay the same, the first value is taken, and the new column is added.

Comment: There are some things that are not clear in your question. 1) What is 'B' in your function? (I suppose it has to be 'mask') 2) What value do you want in the 'values' column in the resulting dataframe? (in the example you show it is the first occuring value) 3) I also suppose the value of 25 in the 'Z' column of you resulting array has to be 20?

Comment: I updated the question with a better example.

Comment: OK, but what does MySQL return for columns where you do not calculate something for (the *)? I think the value of the first occuring row? So that is the same as in my answer.
And what is `action_value`? Did you mean there `'res_value'`?

Comment: Your results are indeed correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the original columns in your result, you can first calculate the grouped and aggregated dataframe (but you will have to aggregate in some way your original columns. I took the first occuring as an example):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[11,11,22,22],'mask':[0,0,0,1],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})
>>> 
>>> grouped = df.groupby("A")
>>> 
>>> result = grouped.agg('first')
>>> result
    mask  values
A               
11     0      10
22     0      20
```

and then add a column 'Z' to that result by applying your function on the groupby result 'grouped':

```
>>> def calculate_df_stats(dfs):
...     mask_ = list(dfs['mask'])
...     mean = np.ma.array(list(dfs['values']), mask=mask_).mean()
...     return mean
... 
>>> result['Z'] = grouped.apply(calculate_df_stats)
>>> 
>>> result
    mask  values     Z
A                     
11     0      10  12.5
22     0      20  20.0
```

In your function definition you can always use more columns (just by their name) to return the result.